# Bypassing a singularity at the zero-frequency in a numerical integral

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, fourier-transform, singularity, singularity-theory

I am attempting to implement a model outlined in this paper:

[General magnetostatic shape–shape interactions](https://jontallen.ece.illinois.edu/Public/Allen1/Noori-pdf/BeleggiaDeGraef.05.pdf)

**Background**

This model allows the calculation of magnetostatic interaction energies between objects of arbitrary shape. I am trying to numerically evaluate the integral shown here:

$$E_m=\dfrac{\overline{K}_d}{4\pi^3}\Re\left[\int d^3\mathbf{k} D_1(\mathbf{k})D_1^*(\mathbf{k})\times (\mathbf{\hat{m}_{1}}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{k}}) (\mathbf{\hat{m}_{2}}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{k}})e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{\rho}}\right]$$

Part of the computation involves the computation of unit vectors in reciprocal space:

$$\mathbf{\hat{k}}= \dfrac{[k_x,k_y,k_z]}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}}= \dfrac{[k_x,k_y,k_z]}{k}$$

Where $k_\alpha$ is a frequency in the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis.

These vectors are grouped in way that you are left with factors like this in the final expression:

$\dfrac{k_x k_z}{k^2}$ or $\dfrac{k_y k_y}{k^2}$

These create singularities at $k=0$ which must be bypassed to complete the numerical calculation.

**Question**

When I try to evaluate the limit (naively with L'Hopital's rule), I find as $\mathbf{k}$ tends to zero for $\dfrac{1}{k^2}$ or $\dfrac{k_x k_z}{k^2}$, the limit is zero or undefined depending on case. That doesn't seem right, because the $k=0$ term corresponds to the large, DC value of $D(\mathbf{k})$, and that shouldn't simply be zeroed or ignored. A colleague suggested I read into "numerical inverse laplacians" but I wasn't able to find anything that seemed relevant. How can this singularity be bypassed?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to write it out in spherical coordinates? I would expect that the additional $k^2$ factor from the Jacobian would show that there are no such singularities at $k=0$. I also don't understand that the limit of $1/k^2$ or $k_xk_y/k^2$ is zero or undefined. Can you give some more details?

Comment: The sum you evaluate when computing the integral numerically looks like this: $\bar{E}_m(\pmb{\rho_{ij}})=\dfrac{1}{L^3} \sum_{\pmb{k}} \left[\dfrac{D_i(\pmb{k})D_j^*(\pmb{k})}{V_i V_j}\right]\left[m_i^\alpha \dfrac{k^\alpha k^\beta}{k^2}m_j^\beta \right]e^{i\pmb{k}\cdot \pmb{\rho_{ij}}} $
. Now, for one term in this series, where $k_x=k_y=k_z=0$, the value of $\dfrac{k^\alpha k^\beta}{k^2}$ equals $\dfrac{0\times0}{0^2+0^2+0^2}=\dfrac{0}{0}$. I am struggling to understand how this term should be handled.

Comment: Well, you should ask yourself how this quotient behaves as $k\rightarrow0$. If you express the $k^\alpha$ components in spherical coordinates, you will realize that $k^\alpha k^\beta/k^2 = f_{\alpha\beta}(\theta, \phi)$, where $f$ is a function of the angles and the particular components you have. There is no _real_ divergence. Numerically, if you want to avoid asking the computer to evaluate 0/0, you can simply avoid a small spherical region around the origin, because the integrand is actually smooth there (proportional to $k^2D_i(k)D_j(k)$ actually)

Comment: Ahhh, okay, so taking as an example $\alpha=\beta=z$, we have $\dfrac{k_z^2}{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}=cos^2(\phi)$ which is clearly not a function of $\rho$. Interesting! So $\dfrac{k_z k_z}{k^2}=f_{zz}(\phi)$. Naive questions incoming: first, if you want to evaluate $f_{zz}(\phi)$ as you close in on the origin from everywhere, could you integrate $cos^2(\phi)$ from zero to $\pi$? Second question: the numerical value $D(\pmb{0})$ is large, wouldn't ignoring this region cause an important inaccuracy in the integral?

Thank you for these replies, by the way!

Comment: First: Yes, you can in principle do the integration in spherical coordinates: $k$ from $0$ to $\infty$, $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$. To do this, you have to remember that $\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}$ becomes $k^2\mathrm{d}k\mathrm{d}\phi\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: Second: It depends, but in principle regions with $k\in[k, k+\mathrm{d}k)$ contribute to the whole integral proportional to $k^2$, because of the size of the integration volume. Hence, close to the origin, your integrand in spherical coordinates is proportional to $k^2$, which will surely cancel the large $D(0)$. As long as $D(k)$ does not diverge quadratically as $k\rightarrow 0$, you will be able to find a small radius that you can exclude _numerically_ while still getting converged results. You may have to play around a bit though to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: Typo: $k^2\mathrm{d}k\mathrm{d}\theta\sin(\phi)\mathrm{d}\phi$